# Detect reverted transaction in web3.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, solidity, web3py

I am trying to detect if a function call is reverted , I am always getting the transaction hash and never fails.

this error is for Web3.py that doesn't provide a callback function with transact ,in web3.js this future is enabled.

```py
def addParticipants(request):
    web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(settings.Blockchain_IP_address, request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
    project_address = '0x93aeD90401a182247EE28848229531bC78053cd6'
    project = web3.eth.contract(address=project_address,
                                abi=Project_sol.abi,
                                bytecode=Project_sol.bytecode)
    func_to_call = 'addParticipant'
    addParticipant = project.functions[func_to_call]
    result = addParticipant(settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT,0).transact(  {'from': settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT, 'gasLimit': '6000000', 'gasPrice': '0', 'gas': 600000})
    web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(result)
    print(result)
```

contract function

```
function addParticipant(address _Participant, uint _weight)public isOwner returns (bool) {
    require(_weight!=0,"weight cannot be null");
    require(status,"this Donation is closed");

    Participants[_Participant].weight = _weight;
    Participants[_Participant].status = true;
    ParticipantsIndex[ParticipantsIndexSize] = _Participant;
    ParticipantsIndexSize++;

    emit ParticipantAction(_Participant, 'added');
    return true;
  }
```

i have to tests,

```
require(_weight!=0,"weight cannot be null");
require(status,"this Donation is closed");
```

It should revert and raise an error if not succeeded , but i am always receiving a transaction hash without errors

Answer (score 3):

You should check the receipt of the transaction.

```py
result = addParticipant(settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT,0).transact(  {'from': settings.ADMIN_ACCOUNT, 'gasLimit': '6000000', 'gasPrice': '0', 'gas': 600000})
receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(result)
print(receipt['status'])
```

If the `status` field is `0`, it means the transaction is reverted.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127298/web3-py-get-transaction